# Return a value after JavaFX Timeline has finished

Tags: java, javafx, timeline

I'm using a timeline in JavaFX to do a countdown of a `Label`:

```
timeline.setCycleCount(6);
timeline.play();
```

And I want to return a value after the timeline has finished:

```
return true;
```

However, it seems that the value is getting returned immediately and the timeline runs parallel. How can I wait until the timeline has finished its countdown and then return the value without blocking the timeline?

EDIT:

To make it more clear, I already tried:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    timeline.play();
}).start();

while(!finished){ // finished is set to true, when the countdown is <=0

}
return true;
```

> (This solution doesn't update the countdown.)

EDIT 2:

Here is a minimal, complete and verifiable example:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class CountdownTest extends Application {

    private Label CountdownLabel;
    private int Ctime;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        CountdownLabel=new Label(Ctime+"");

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(CountdownLabel);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Countdown Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Ctime=5;

        if(myCountdown()){
            CountdownLabel.setText("COUNTDOWN FINISHED");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public boolean myCountdown(){
         final Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                            new KeyFrame(
                                    Duration.millis(1000),
                                    event -> {
                                    CountdownLabel.setText(Ctime+"");
                                    Ctime--;

                                    }

                            )
                    );
         timeline.setCycleCount(6);
         timeline.play();
    return true;
    }

}
```

You can see that it first shows "COUNTDOWN FINISHED" and counts down to 0 instead of starting with the countdown and counting down to "COUNTDOWN FINISHED".

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I added a MCVE to make it more clear.

Comment: good :) just (unrelated to your problem): please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: you are simply using the timeline incorrectly as already explained in the answers .. why don't you incorporate the suggestions and show us why they don't fit your requirements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a [`Timeline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) inherits from `Animation`, you can use [`setOnFinished`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#setOnFinished-javafx.event.EventHandler-) to define an action to occur at the end of the timeline.

```
timeline.setCycleCount(6);
timeline.play();
timeline.setOnFinished(event -> countdownLabel.setText("COUNTDOWN FINISHED"));
```

Comment: Already tried this. How can I return a value inside of it to the outer function?

Comment: You cannot do that without delaying execution of the thread that the timeline is on. What are you using that return value for?

Comment: @user3776738 See my updated answer for how to utilize `setOnFinished` in your case.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to wait till the timeline finished, you can use a `CountDownLatch` or a `Semaphore` along with `setOnFinished`. Something like the following should work:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
timeline.setCycleCount(6);
timeline.setOnFinished(event -> latch.countDown());
timeline.play();
latch.await();
return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to wait in the one thread for the result of the work in the another thread. That is what [synchronisation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) was created for! E.g. `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`:

```
public boolean waitForTimeline()  {
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);

    System.out.println("starting timeline");
    Timeline t = new Timeline();
    t.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2)));
    t.setOnFinished((e)-> {
        System.out.println("releasing semaphore"); 
        semaphore.release();
    });
    t.play();

    System.out.println("waiting for timeline to end");
    try {
        semaphore.acquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But note, that you can't run this method on "JavaFX Application Thread" as it will block UI updates. Run it on a separate thread:

```
new Thread(()-> { 
    System.out.println("returned from timeline with " + waitForTimeline()); 
}).start();
```

or, better, instead create a listener with the logic you do after `return` and call that listener from `t.setOnFinished()`. For your example, it will be:

```
public void myCountdown(Runnable onSuccess){
    //...
    timeline.setOnFinished((e)-> {
        onSuccess.run();
    });
}
```

and corresponding call:

```
myCountdown(()->{
    CountdownLabel.setText("COUNTDOWN FINISHED");
});
```

Comment: Imho using a `Consumer<Boolean>` would be closer to the original code (you pass a value to the "finished handler"), but in this case a `Runnable` should do the trick... (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Animation`'s `setOnFinished` in addition to the `KeyFrame`'s `setOnFinished` that you have (a `Timeline` is an `Animation`). Iv'e modified your MCVE to show how to do that for your case:

```
public class CountdownTest extends Application {

    private Label countdownLabel;
    private int ctime = 5;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        countdownLabel = new Label();

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(countdownLabel);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Countdown Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        myCountdown();
    }

    public void myCountdown() {
        final Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000),
            event -> {
                countdownLabel.setText(ctime + "");
                ctime--;
            }
        ));
        timeline.setCycleCount(ctime + 1);
        timeline.setOnFinished(e -> countdownLabel.setText("COUNTDOWN FINISHED"));
        timeline.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

On each cycle, the `KeyFrame`'s `setOnFinished` will be executed, reducing the count by 1. When the whole animation finishes (all of its cycles), the `Timeline`'s `setOnFinished` will be executed.

**Notes:**

- Use the `ctime` variable to calculate the number of cycles so that they match.
- Use the Java naming conventions: identifiers (names) start with lowercase.
- Indent your code properly so that it's easier to read.